# How to place theses find values using bs4 in csv file one cell each?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[You can see each character is separated by coma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBqdr.png)
[And placed in separate cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BYWv.png)

I want to placed a value in a single cell

This is the code i want to place each value in a single cell:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from csv import writer

url = 'https://whatmobile.web.pk/search/all?price-range=21721-50681&search=all&title=Mobile+Prices+%3E+RS.+100%2C000+and+Above'
website = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(website.content, 'html.parser')
lists = soup.find_all('div', class_='product-grid8')

with open('file.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as file:
    thewriter = writer(file)
    header = ['price']
    thewriter.writerow(header)
    for i in lists:
        price = i.find('div', class_='small').text
        newprice = price.replace(' PKR ', '')

        p = float(newprice)
        if p < 40000:
            thewriter.writerow(price)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get those prices and phone names:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

url = 'https://whatmobile.web.pk/search/all?price-range=21721-50681&search=all&title=Mobile+Prices+%3E+RS.+100%2C000+and+Above'
big_list = []
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
phones = soup.select('div[class="product-grid8"]')
for p in phones:
    price = p.select_one('div[class="price small text-center"]').text.strip().replace('PKR', '')
    title = p.select_one('h2[class="title mb-0 w-100 text-center"]').text.strip()
    big_list.append((price, title))
df = pd.DataFrame(big_list, columns=['price', 'title'])
print(df)
df.to_csv('phone_prices.csv')
```

Result in terminal:

```
    price   title
0   38999.00    Honor Play 30m
1   46999.00    Huawei Nova Y61
2   26999.00    Oppo A17K
3   43999.00    Tecno Spark 9 Pro Sport Edition
4   34999.00    Infinix Hot 20s
5   35999.00    Honor Play 6C
6   26999.00    Itel S18 Pro
7   33999.00    Samsung Galaxy A04e
8   33999.00    Infinix Hot 20i
9   28999.00    Infinix Hot 20 Play
```

Results will also be saved as csv.